# Roblox MouseButton1Down click not working

Tags: lua, roblox

I tried several ways, but nothing worked. There's my code now:

```
script.Parent.MouseButton1Down:Connect(function()
    print("adding money to your account...")
    if game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.Money.Value == 0 then
        game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.Money.Value = 1
        return
    end
    game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.Money.Value = game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.Money.Value + 1
    print("done")
end)
```

I know using this game.Players.LocalPlayer is not the best way, I already tried like this:

```
script.Parent.MouseButton1Down:Connect(function(plr)
    print("adding money to your account...")
    if plr.leaderstats.Money.Value == 0 then
        plr.leaderstats.Money.Value = 1
        return
    end
    plr.leaderstats.Money.Value = plr.leaderstats.Money.Value + 1
    print("done")
end)
```

Comment: What does it do instead of working? Is there any output? Is this a Script or a LocalScript?

Comment: You don't need to handle the `== 0` case differently. 0 + 1 is 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wsha's answer is correct but here's the explanation.

Lets say we have a basic addition script here:

```
number1 = 0
```

And we want to add 1 to that. By just typing:

```
number1 + 1
```

You're essentially adding 1 to the variable itself, and not the variables value. So by referencing the variables value using:

```
number1 = number1 + 1
```

The script knows that the new value in the number 1 variable is the current value add 1.

Comment: Thanks, but.. I have another problem now..
script.Parent.MouseButton1Down:Connect(function(plr)
 game.StarterGui.Cash.Enabled = true
 game.StarterGui.CashGUI.Enabled = false
end)
this is not working:c

Comment: Ok I see your issue. You're directly referencing the StarterGui, not the individual player StarterGui. To put this into readable terms, when a roblox server is initialised, the player gets a copy of StarterGui. Now your script is working, but it's referencing it globally. So instead of going to lets say a username is 'builderman'; 'builderman.StarterGui.Cash.enabled ect..' it's going to 'server.StarterGui.Cash.enabled'. It also wouldn't be called 'StarterGui' either. It would be called I believe 'PlayerGui' or along those lines. Where you have got the 'function(plr)', the 'plr

Comment: is the part where you want to reference, so instead of 'game.StarterGui...' put 'plr.StarterGui.....' or the correct term. I would get the exact term but I do not have access to Roblox studio currently. If you need more clarification, add me on Roblox 'E_Link'.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This should suffice

```
script.Parent.MouseButton1Down:Connect(function(plr)
    print("adding money to your account...")
    game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.Money.Value = 
    game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.Money.Value + 1
    print("done")
return
```